# MapHttpRoute root url for web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to change my root url of my web api to run an action, however when using attempting to map, I get an error at runtime saying that I cannot use `/` or `~` as my route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("RootInformation", "/", new {controller = "Core", action = "GetInformation"});
```

How do I go about adding this root URL route

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RootInformation", 
        routeTemplate: "", 
        defaults: new 
        {
             Controller = "Core", 
             Action = "GetInformation"
        }
 );
```

Comment: or use the `[Route("")]` attribute on the action